# Mailto link behaviour different between chrome and firefox for accented characters

Tags: javascript, email, firefox, google-chrome, mailto

I have an web application that allows a user to invite others by popping up an email. The problem is that for French users this email contains accented characters and the email fails to open in firefox with then error:

Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMLocation.href]

I've got this down to how the accent is being encoded and can reproduce it easily with the following code:

```
document.location.href = 'mailto:?body=' + escape("à");
```

is broken in firefox but works in Chrome and IE.

```
document.location.href = 'mailto:?body=' + encodeURIComponent("à");
```

works in firefox but produces the wrong character in the email body when using Chrome and IE ("Ã")

My question is therefore - how should I be encoding special characters in mailto links such that they work across browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the character encoding of the page that includes the script in question?

Comment: That said, I just tried the encodeURIComponent version in Safari and Chrome, and it works in both... but on Windows it might end up depending on what codepage you're using?